# rsync command copying files that have been already copy and didn't change

Tags: rsync

I'm new with `rsync` command, so maybe I'm doing something wrong or I misunderstood something.
I have a source folder with some files and one folder with files. I want to backup all this content in a external device (using a FAT32 filesystem). I'm running this command to do this:

```bash
rsync -av /home/user/test_rsync/ /media/user/4GB_DEVICE/backup/
```

And everything works as expected:

```
sending incremental file list
./
IMG_20221207_131446.jpg
IMG_20221207_200136.jpg
IMG_20221207_200149.jpg
IMG_20221207_200157.jpg
IMG_20221207_204333.jpg
IMG_20221207_233821.jpg
IMG_20221207_234220.jpg
IMG_20221208_044933.jpg
IMG_20221208_124239.jpg
IMG_20221208_124253.jpg
IMG_20221208_124515.jpg
IMG_20221209_012246.jpg
IMG_20221209_102019.jpg
IMG_20221209_113906.jpg
IMG_20221209_113947.jpg
folder/
folder/IMG_20221209_174723.jpg
folder/IMG_20221209_194201.jpg

sent 51.762.068 bytes  received 354 bytes  3.834.253,48 bytes/sec
total size is 51.748.270  speedup is 1,00
```

And now, if I immediately run the same command:

```
rsync -av /home/user/test_rsync/ /media/user/4GB_DEVICE/backup/ --dry-run
sending incremental file list
./
IMG_20221207_200136.jpg
IMG_20221207_204333.jpg
IMG_20221209_102019.jpg
IMG_20221209_113906.jpg
IMG_20221209_113947.jpg
folder/
folder/IMG_20221209_194201.jpg

sent 554 bytes  received 74 bytes  1.256,00 bytes/sec
total size is 51.748.270  speedup is 82.401,70 (DRY RUN)
```

It looks that `rsync` is going to copy some files, but not all. I would expect that `rsync` to do nothing, because all content is exactly the same and none of files and folder changed. I would like to avoid copying files that already are in the destination folder unless they have been modified.

I tried with `-c` option, and the output was better, but even so, it looks that rsync is going to do something with the folder:

```
rsync -avc /home/user/test_rsync/ /media/user/4GB_DEVICE/backup/ --dry-run
sending incremental file list
./
folder/

sent 826 bytes  received 74 bytes  1.800,00 bytes/sec
total size is 51.748.270  speedup is 57.498,08 (DRY RUN)
```

Comment: Thanks @ChrisDavies. Your link was really useful and it looks that my problem has been solved with the information provided in the post. I'm considering to remove the question, although in my case unplug and replug my device didn't change the result and rsync wants to copy the same files, but not all the files. I'm going to try with ext4 filesystem as well, and I will compare the results.